# Get first and last character in string with javascript and create substring

Tags: javascript, substring

Hello if I have a string that is like

```
"[[{abc}, {abc}, {abc}]]....blah".
```

How can I get it to just be

```
"[{abc}, {abc}, {abc}]"
```

I want to start with the first "[" and end with the last "]" I tried substring but it only works if the string length never changes.

```
var newString = oldstring.substring(1) //this starts at the second "[" but how to continue till the last "]"?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the expected string using `startIndex` as `1` and `endIndex`as `str.length - 1`

```js
const str = "[[{abc}, {abc}, {abc}]]";
const newString = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
console.log(newString);
```

If you are looking to get the string after the very first `[` and before the last `]`,  then you can do as:

```js
const str = "[[{abc}, {abc}, {abc}]]";
const strArr = str.split("");
const newString = str.substring(
  strArr.indexOf("[") + 1,
  strArr.lastIndexOf("]")
);
console.log(newString);
```

Comment: Thanks, your second solutions works great!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
const str = "[[{abc}, {abc}, {abc}]]";

const result = str.slice(1, -1);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: A very good alternative to a solution using `substring`!